# Extract any different from zero value from one row

Tags: excel, extract

I have a table with many columns. Each column is for separate calendar date.
Table is automatically updated from other source.
First row consists of the calendar dates.
In sixth row only in some columns, there is a number.
I want Excel to find each number in 6th row and the corresponding calendar date from the first row, same column.

```
20/9/14   21/9/14   22/9/14   23/9/14   24/9/14

   0         0        2.5        0        3.2
```

Would like to have result as:

```
22/9/14   24/9/14 

  2.5      3.2
```

Comment: And what should happen with the result.

Comment: The result will be displayed on the graphs in order to be compared.

Comment: I tried to use INDEX formula

Comment: I tried to use INDEX formula =INDEX(B$31:HC$31,MATCH(0,B$32:HC$32,1)+1) I tried to find a way to find the numbers by conditional formatting the cells with the numbers. The only way probably I may use is to make other table linked to the original and ask each cell contains number > 0 to be displayed as 1 for example and then with HLOOKUP to find the corresponding date. Then by the found date to find real number in the original table....it should be better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you just want to visualize the data in a chart and the cells really are empty (not 0) you can show your data in a chart. There is a setting that empty cells are omitted and the non-empty cells are connected by the lines. If the cells are not empty but `0`, you can insert a new row with formula `=IF(A6=0,"",A6)`
2. You can copy your whole data range and paste it in a new sheet with special option 'transpose'. Then you can filter the newly created column for empty cells.
3. Otherwise I think you have to use VBA. I don't think that it is possible to create your desired range by formulas as the size of the target range is unknown and depends on the source data.

Comment: Thank You Fratyx! The first option you offer works. Second with the "transpose" function is not working as I need to copy formulas as well due to future automatic update of the table. Thank You once again, actually all what I do is to make visualization, something like Dashboard in order to detect abnormal changes on daily basis.